# How do I log or trace using shinytest?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to be able to see what happens inside the `reactive({...})` parts in my code. I thought that using shinytest could be a way to execute parts of my application which use `Shiny Modules` and learn about `callModule`.

I tried the following in my code to log/trace/print.

```
print("hello1")
message("hello2")
cat(file=stderr(), "hello3")
logging::loginfo("hello4")
```

runtest.R

```
library(shinytest)
testApp("/home/eddy/rwork/filters", "mytest")
viewTestDiff("/home/eddy/rwork/filters", interactive = FALSE)
```

output:

```
Rscript runtest.R
Running mytest.R 
==== Comparing mytest... No changes.
==== mytest ====
No differences between expected and current results
```

How can I add some trace output to the test run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a really convenient way to see app output in shinytest right now, but there is this method on ShinyDriver objects:

> `app$getDebugLog()` queries one or more of the debug logs: `shiny_console`, `browser` or `shinytest`.
>
> https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/reference/ShinyDriver.html

You could use this with the `shiny_console` option to print app output in individual tests like:

```
# mytest.R

app <- ShinyDriver$new()

...

log <- app$getDebugLog("shiny_console")
print(log)
```

Answer (score 2):

**shinytest** integrates with the **shiny** concept of export values while in test, so you can use the function, [`shiny::exportTestValues()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/exportTestValues.html) to create a named expressions with the values, including the reactive, you want to export.

For example, if you had the reactive data.frame, `scaledData`, that used some sort of input binding in your app code, you could do the following:

```
scaledData <- reactive({
  dummyData[, "y"] <- dummyData[, "y"] * input$scale
  return(dummyData)
})

# The scaledData will be captured as a json object in the shinytest output
exportTestValues(scaledData = scaledData())
```

This will capture the reactive value in the snapshot under the `exports` key in the json file, so you can then use this in your test comparisons (as well as view the data if you'd like).

One last note is that these export values only get run when the app is in test mode, e.g. `isTRUE(getOption("shiny.testmode"))`.

I wrote a blog post about how I use this to test DataTables in shiny, you can read that here: https://nadirsidi.github.io/Shinytest/.

Answer (score 1):

You can alocate an print(), cat(), warning() inside your reactive function to check value o class of your object inside R prompt. This works for me using only Shinny in RStudio without shinytest.
Additioanlly, as you said its not working the previous options, you can place a `write.myformat()` function in order to write any kind of object and check it externally.